# Compare objects on property and child properties using expressions

Tags: c#, expression-trees, expression

I have the following method to compare DTOs.

```
bool Equals<T1, T2>(T1 t1, T2 t2, params Expression<Func<T1, object>>[] accessors)
{
  return !(
    from accessor in accessors 
    select ((MemberExpression) accessor.Body).Member.Name into propertyName 
    let p1 = typeof (T1).GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly) 
    let p2 = typeof (T2).GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly) 
    let p1val = p1.GetValue(t1, null) 
    let p2val = p2.GetValue(t2, null) 
    where !Equals(p1val, p2val) 
    select p1val
  ).Any();
}
```

I can call this using (`a` and `b` are instances of objects that by convention share the same properties, but that aren't the same objects):

```
Equals(a, b, x => x.PropertyOne, x => x.PropertyTwo );
```

Which compares the the objects property by property, which is fine for most cases.

However, I found a case where I needed to compare objects that had properties of complex types and where I wanted to compare properties on the complex types instead of the objects. Something like this:

```
Equals(a, b, x => x.ComplexTypeProperty.ChildProp );
```

I have realised that I need to leave the comfy reflection comparison and enter the Expression land, but the main task here is to be able to *express* both a property accessor and a property accessor via a complex type property and that's where I'm lost.

Any pointers would be nice, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task is not so complicated:

1. Determine property path or expressions that are given by expressions. For instance this extension method will give you this:

   ```
   public static IEnumerable<string> GetPropertiesNames<T, G>(this Expression<Func<T, G>> pathExpression)
   {
       List<string> _propertyNames = new List<string>();

       Expression expression = pathExpression.Body;

       if (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
       {
           var convert = (UnaryExpression)pathExpression.Body;
           expression = convert.Operand;
       }

       while (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
       {
           MemberExpression memberExpression = (MemberExpression)expression;
             if(!(memberExpression.Member is PropertyInfo)) 
                   throw new InvalidOperationException();
           _propertyNames.Add(memberExpression.Member.Name);
           expression = memberExpression.Expression;
       }

       if (expression.NodeType != ExpressionType.Parameter)
           throw new InvalidOperationException();

       return _propertyNames;
   }
   ```
2. Aggregate expression for second type to create function that will return value:

   ```
   var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2));      
   var expressionToConvert =  accessors[0]; //for future loop

       var propertyChainDescriptor = expressionToConvert.GetPropertiesNames() 
            .Aggregate(new { Expression = (Expression)parameterCasted, Type = typeof(T2)},
                (current, propertyName) =>
                {
                    var property = current.Type.GetProperty(propertyName);
                    var expression = Expression.Property(current.Expression, property);
                    return new { Expression = (Expression)expression, Type = property.PropertyType };
                });

       var body = propertyChainDescriptor.Expression;

       if (propertyChainDescriptor.Type.IsValueType)
       {
           body = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object));
       }

       var t2PropertyRetriver = Expression.Lambda<Func<T2, object>>(body, parameter).Compile();
   ```
3. Now execute method that retrieve values and compare:

   ```
       var t1PropertyRetriver = accessor[0].Compile();
       var t1Value = t1PropertyRetriver(t1);
       var t2Value = t2PropertyRetriver(t2);

       var areEqual = object.Equals(t1Value,t2Value);
   ```

The good idea would be to add some caching of generated methods because compilation process is expensive.